# get the span title for each language and insert in a new span

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-manipulation

I have the following piece of html (in a cms environment):

```
<div id="languageswitch">
    <div class="language-object">
        <span class="Language selected" title="English (United States)">
        </span>
        <span class="Language" title="Nederlands (Nederland)">
            <a href="http://mylocalwebsite.nl/nl-nl/">
            </a>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

So I want to get the span title of each language and insert and wrap it in another span with the class text. The HTML result should look like this:

```
<div id="languageswitch">
    <div class="language-object">
        <span class="Language selected" title="English (United States)">
            <span class="text">Eng</span>
        </span>
        <span class="Language" title="Nederlands (Nederland)">
            <a href="http://mylocalwebsite.nl/nl-nl/">
                <span class="text">Ned</span>
            </a>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

So far my solution isn't working correctly because the text of the two languages are getting the same, instead of two:

```
//get the span.Language title
var getLanguageTitle = $('#languageswitch').children("div").children("span").attr("title");
//insert new spans to show the span titles
$('#languageswitch span').each(function () {
    $(this).append("<span class='text'></span>");
});
$('span.text').append(getLanguageTitle);
```

My jsfiddle is: http://jsfiddle.net/7tjb1fw7/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the exact result you want, try this:

```js
$('#languageswitch span.Language').each(function () {
  // fetch first 3 letters of the language:
  var lang = $.trim($(this).attr("title")).slice(0,3);
  var a = $(this).find('a');
  // check if the span contains anchor element:
  if(a.length){
    // if so, update html of the link
    a.html("<span class='text'>"+lang+"</span>");
  }else{
     // if not, append span:
     $(this).append("<span class='text'>"+lang+"</span>");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="languageswitch">
    <div class="language-object">
        <span class="Language selected" title="English (United States)">
        </span>
        <span class="Language" title="Nederlands (Nederland)">
            <a href="http://mylocalwebsite.nl/nl-nl/">
            </a>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I wanted. Thanks a lot Artur!

Answer (score 2):

You're overcomplicating things:

```
$('.Language').each(function () {
    var txt = $(this).attr('title');
    $(this).append("<span class='text'>" + txt + "</span>");
});
```

#### JS Fiddle Demo

---

**Edit**: If you want to check for a link, you could do this:

```
$('.Language').each(function () {
    var txt = "<span class='text'>" + $(this).attr('title') + "</span>",
        link = $('a', this);
    if(link.length){ link.append(txt); }
    else { $(this).append(txt); }
});
```

### JS Fiddle Demo

Comment: thanks for your answer, but the second span (span without the Selected class) should be inside the a href. So how do I check on this?